# How to fill empty lines from one file with corresponding lines from another file, in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. Each has an identical number of lines, but some of the lines in `file1.txt` are empty. This is easiest to see when the content of the two files is displayed in parallel:

```
file1.txt     file2.txt
cat           bear
fish          eagle
spider        leopard
              snail
catfish       rainbow trout
              snake
              koala
rabbit        fish
```

I need to assemble these files together, such that the empty lines in `file1.txt` are filled with the data found in the lines (of the same line number) from `file2.txt`. The result in `file3.txt` would look like this:

```
cat
fish
spider
snail
catfish
snake
koala
rabbit
```

The best I can do so far, is create a `while read -r line` loop, create a counter that counts how many times the while loop has looped, then use an if-conditional to check if `$line` is empty, then use `cut` to obtain the line number from `file2.txt` according to the number on the counter. This method seems really inefficient.

- Sometimes `file2.txt` might contain some empty lines. If `file1.txt` has an empty line and `file2.txt` also has an empty line in the same place, the result is an empty line in `file3.txt`.

How can I fill the empty lines in one file with corresponding lines from another file?

Answer (score 4):

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk -F '\t' '$1 { print $1 ; next } { print $2 }'
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `paste` :)

Comment: This will fail if there are value with in `file1` with tab, like `more catfish`, it will print only `more` (first word before tab), see workaround posted by @Homayoun Afshari using `paste -d"#"` but it will also fail if data contains `#`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way to handle these files with  `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print (NF?$0:a[FNR])}' file2 file1
cat
fish
spider
snail
catfish
snake
koala
rabbit
```

First it store every data of the `file2` in array `a` using record number as index
Then it prints `file1`, bit it thest if `file1` contains data for each record
If there is data for this record, then use it, if not get one from `file2`

Comment: +1: Can be shortened to `awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$0=$0?$0:a[FNR]}1' file2 file1`

Comment: That will fail if the line in file1 is populated with anything that evaluates to the number zero (e.g. 0 or 0.0 or ...). You also need to parenthesize the ternary expression for portability. Change it to `awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print (NF?$0:a[FNR])}' file2 file1`.

Comment: Parenthesize added. I do need to remember the portability :)

Comment: The first part of the comment about testing `NF` instead of `$0` to see if a line is empty was actually the more important part IMHO. Or you could test `$0 == ""` if you want to treat lines of just space chars differently from totally empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

One with getline (harmless in this case) :

```
awk '{getline p<f; print NF?$0:p; p=x}' f=file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | sed -E 's/^   //g' | cut -f1
```

This deletes tabs that are at the beginning of a line (those missing from file1) and then takes the first column.

(For OSX, `\t` doesn't work in sed, so to get the TAB character, you type ctrl-V then Tab)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Bash only solution.

```
for i in 1 2; do
    while read line; do
        if [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
            arr1+=("$line")
        else
            arr2+=("$line")
        fi
    done < file${i}.txt
done
for r in ${!arr1[@]}; do
    if [[ -n ${arr1[$r]} ]]; then
            echo ${arr1[$r]}
    else
            echo ${arr2[$r]}
    fi
done > file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution without awk :

```
paste -d"#" file1 file2 | sed 's/^#\(.*\)/\1/' | cut -d"#" -f1
```